# HTML Header Content Security Policy not reporting to file

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, content-security-policy

After reading [an introduction to CSP](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) and the [CSP website](http://content-security-policy.com/) I wanted to get a feedback log of CSP breaches on my website.

So, I set up a header in my `.htaccess` as defined in the links above:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.jscache.com;"
```

This **works**, but for various reasons there are other entities that are still being blocked, so I want to setup a CSP *report*. Again, something that is clearly explained in the documents linked above.

And back to my `.htaccess` I replace the line with:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; report-uri /csp_report_parser.txt;"
```

Which I want to report all the non-self requests into a file, `/csp_report_parser.txt` . This file I have created on the same place as the `.htaccess` but the file fails to be populated, despite feedback from firebug stating:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings observed the loading of a resource at https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js ("default-src http://mywebsite"). A CSP report is being sent.

and many of these each time stating "A CSP report is being sent". The file this report should be sent to exists and I have given permissions 777 yet the file remains blank.

**What have I missed to make this reporting feedback into the file stated?**

I have also tried specifying an absolute URL to report to such as :

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; report-uri http://mywebsite/csp_report_parser.txt;"
```

But again, this file on my domain remains blank despite browser firebug statements as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was expecting a data dump in a JSON format what I actually neeeded was to process the passed data to be dumped *first*, using a PHP `json_decode` function before saving the data to the file.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
file_put_contents('csp_report_parser.txt',print_r($data,true),FILE_APPEND);
```